# Definitive file path to a cell location using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering how to define the specific file path to a cell location using Excel VBA? I am trying to load a value to `nCount` which is the count in another file in a defined location. So more like assigning the value from a cell to `nCount`.

```
nCount = "G:\ABC\[FILE FOR 2016-2017.xlsx]Master!$A$1"
```

It gives me an error:

> Run-time error '13:"; "Type Mismatch

Answer (score 0):

You can get a value from a closed workbook using and *Excel4* macro.  Here is a typical example:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wbPath As String, wbName As String
    Dim wsName As String, CellRef As String
    Dim Ret As String

    wbPath = "C:\TestFolder\"
    wbName = "ABC.xls"
    wsName = "xxx"
    CellRef = "B9"

    Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
          wsName & "'!" & Range(CellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

    MsgBox Ret & vbCrLf & ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

End Sub
```

[image]